# Trying to return data via completion handler from a URLSession

Tags: swift, urlsession

I hope someone can help, I've tried several tutorials and I'm close to getting this working, I think.

I have a struct defined, called Patient. It contains dozens of key: value pairs and is identical to the information from a JSON response. I'm able to print this response in the console in Xcode and it looks fine. What I'm trying to do is populate the struct with the JSON data and return it via completion handler for use in the rest of the app.

Where I keep tripping up is in returning the populated struct, the code below gives me the error at the point where the completion block is:

"Cannot convert value of type '(Patient).Type' to expected argument type 'Patient'"

I suspect I'm just very confused and I'm missing something obvious. Any help with walking me through this is greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
import Foundation

func getReturnA(doneStuffBlock: @escaping (Patient) -> Void) {

    var patient: [Patient] = []

    // set up URL request
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://***.***.***.***/backend/returnA") else {
        print("Can't create URL")
        return 
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            print("Did not recieve data")
            return
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let patient = try decoder.decode(Array<Patient>.self, from: data)
            print(patient.self)
        } catch let err {
            print("Err", err)
        }
        doneStuffBlock(Patient)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The type in the completion handler is supposed to be an array

   ```
   func getReturnA(doneStuffBlock: @escaping ([Patient]) -> Void) {
   ```
2. Case sensitivity matters (The type `Patient` vs. the variable name `patient`).
   It's recommended to name a variable representing an array in plural form and return an empty array in case of an error.

   <strike>`var patient: [Patient] = []`</strike>

   ```
   ...

   do {
       let decoder = JSONDecoder()
       let patients = try decoder.decode(Array<Patient>.self, from: data)
       print(patients)
       doneStuffBlock(patients)
   } catch {
       print("Err", error)
       doneStuffBlock([])
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now.